# Is there a XML Schema (xsd) to AsciiDoc converter?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I wonder whether there exists a tool which converts the descriptions contained in an XML xsd to an AsciiDoc table so that this can be included in an overall AsciiDoc document.

The benefit would be of course to have only a single source of description, avoiding copy & paste.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no there is not. You could do it with xslt, or any other language that reads xml.